# function to return a string based on integer value statues php only appears onced

Tags: php, html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor='#89ff8'>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
         <td>Trade</td>
        <td>registration Date</td>
        <td>View Info</td>
    </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
    <?php 

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['LastName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".numToTrade($res['Trade'])."</td>"; 
         echo "<td>".$res['DateRegistered']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href=\"artisaninfo.php?id=$res[ArtisanId]\">view info</a></td>";        
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
<?php    
    function numToTrade($num) {
        $trade = null;
        if ($num == 1) {
            $trade= 'Plumber';
        }
        elseif($num==2) {
            $trade = 'Electrician';
        }  elseif ($num==3) {
            $trade = 'Carpenter';
        } elseif ($num==4) {
            $trade = 'Mechanic';
        } elseif ($num==5) {
            $trade = 'Ac-Technician';
        } elseif ($num==6) {
            $trade = 'Painter';
        } 
        return $trade;
    } 
?>
```

> *function to return a string based on integer value statues php only appears onced. for all table rows the trade column is not rendering integer as it should in php*

please help me.

*function to return a string based on integer value statues php only appears onced. for all table rows the trade column is not rendering integer as it should in php*

Comment: This sounds like homework...

Comment: the code actually worked for me I just created a faster version of the function

Answer (score 0):

```
function numToTrade($num) {

    if ($num == 1) {
       return 'Plumber';
    }
    elseif($num==2) {
      return 'Electrician';
    }  elseif ($num==3) {
       return 'Carpenter';
    } elseif ($num==4) {
        return 'Mechanic';
    } elseif ($num==5) {
        return 'Ac-Technician';
    } elseif ($num==6) {
        return 'Painter';
    } 
}
?>
```

A faster version of the code worked for me